# In an if statement inside of a map, "Expected ']'" shows up

Tags: c++, for-loop, mapping

I'm currently in the early stages of using a range-based for loop and a map to compare the items in an array, however when in the line "if (WordSeen[Word]) {" this error pops up:[image]

I can probably find out the problems behind the rest of the errors on my own, but I am puzzled as to why the "expected "]" pops up. This is the code written in my function:

```
FString FDeclarations::CheckDuplicate()
{
    int a = 1;

    TMap<FString, bool> WordSeen; //settting up the map
    for (auto Word : Item) //for all words inside of the array
        Word = Item [a];

    if (WordSeen[Word]) {// if the word is in the array
        return "something";
    }




    return "Nothing";
}
```

Please let me know if you have any answers, and if you need me to post any other sections of my code. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: Fix the error `undeclared identifier "Word"`, then see what happens.

Comment: `Word` is not declared in the scope of the `if`

Comment: That code doesn't make much sense. You declare an empty map, then iterate over some unknown container named Item and assign the same potentially out of range value to a likely non-reference variable, doing nothing, then you want to look in the empty map to see if a value is in it. You could just delete everything but `return "Nothing";` and get the same result, plus as a bonus, no compile error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mention in the comments to your question, the errors are compounding on each other, the compiler is warning you that `Word` is an `undeclared identifier`. What you missed is the scope of the `for` loop. Which is highlighted by the auto formatted syntax in your snippet. For a in-depth explanation [read this article](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope).

However I'll give you a hint for a common beginners mistake when using the range based for loop but I highly suggest you read all about it [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) to have a better understanding.

```
FString LightExample()
{
   TMap<FString, bool> WordSeen = { { "One", false }, { "Two", true } };
   for (auto Word // This is a copy to the 'next' element in WordSeen from begin() to end()
             : WordSeen /* This is the range based container which will be iterated through */ )
   {
       // Word will be a pair of FString ( first part ) and bool ( second part )
       if( Word.second ) // If the word was seen...
       {
           return Word.first; // return that word!
           // NOTE: it will only ever return the first word seen
           // since it is iterating in order through the map
       }
   }
   return "Nothing";
}
```